# Grammar where braces have lower precedence

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, operator-precedence

I have the following grammar. I want to somehow convert this into a grammar where '()' has lower precedence than '-' and '/'

```
E -> E - E | T
T -> T / T | F 
F -> id | ( E )
```

I have been trying to do this for a while now, it would be great if somebody could help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm not sure that's possible, because the parens are on both sides, so no matter what the precedence, the parens still group the stuff inside them.

Comment: I think you put the word "precedence" in the wrong context. Try showing how the parse tree differs from the desired one.